How can we securely add app details in client side for react-native-fbsdk-next
The react-native-fbsdk-next library suggests adding the facebook app details like appId, clientToken, etc in the AndroidManifest.xml/info.plist files.
As i do not want to expose these details, can we add these details securely or in an encrypted format in the code?
Please do suggest if there is any other workaround or implementation available for facebook login in my react native app.
I tried checking all over the internet but with no luck.

I checked here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/security/ and it says:
"Access tokens are opaque strings that are used in token-based authentication to identify a user, app, or page and can allow an application to access an API. These are considered sensitive and should be kept confidential at all times, as stated in our Platform Term"
and
". Therefore, your app should never have an access token hard-coded into it. Instead, calls should be made directly with the response from the access token generation request."
So you should be dynamically generating these in your app
